# Copy a part of an std::string in a char* pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stdstring

Let's suppose I've this code snippet in C++

```
char* str;
std::string data = "This is a string.";
```

I need to copy the string `data` (except the first and the last characters) in `str`.
My solution that seems to work is creating a substring and then performing the `std::copy` operation like this

```
std::string substring = data.substr(1, size - 2);
str = new char[size - 1];
std::copy(substring.begin(), substring.end(), str);
str[size - 2] = '\0';
```

But maybe this is a bit overkilling because I create a new string. Is there a simpler way to achieve this goal? Maybe working with **offets** in the `std:copy` calls?

Thanks

Comment: You can copy from `.begin()+1` to `.end()-1` if the string is longer than 1.

Comment: You can use `substring.c_str()` if this is suitable for your application. Or does it have to be allocated with `new[]` ?

Comment: I'd use the member function [`std::string::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy), which can copy a substring to a `char *`.

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically create a new string?  Why not create another smaller `std::string`, and pass `c_str()` to whatever function you are interfacing with?  Or if the function modifies the string -- `std::string smallerString; ... some_c_func(&smallerString[0]);`

Comment: "I need to copy the string" Probably an XY problem. Why do you need a C-style string in the first place?

Comment: Can you use C++17? There is `std::string_view`!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you should consider keeping the sub-string as a `std::string` and use [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method when you need to access the underlying chars.

**However-**
If you must create the new string as a dynamic `char` array via `new` you can use the code below.

It checks whether `data` is long enough, and if so allocates memory for `str` and uses `std::copy` similarly to your code, but with **adapted iterators**.

**Note:** there is no need to allocate a temporary `std::string` for the sub-string.

**The Code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::string data = "This is a string.";
    auto len = data.length();
    char* str = nullptr;
    if (len > 2)
    {
        auto new_len = len - 2;
        str = new char[new_len+1];  // add 1 for zero termination
        std::copy(data.begin() + 1, data.end() - 1, str);  // copy from 2nd char till one before the last
        str[new_len] = '\0';  // add zero termination
        std::cout << str << std::endl;

       // ... use str

       delete[] str;    // must be released eventually
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
his is a string
```

Comment: If condition 'if (len > 2)' fails what for is to delete table 'delete[] str;'

Comment: In this case `str` will stay `nullptr` and `delete` will simply do nothing. But I agree it might be better to do inside the `if` to match the deallocation with the allocation. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is:

```
int length = data.length() - 1;
memcpy(str, data.c_str() + 1, length);
str[length] = 0;
```

This will copy the string in data, starting at position `[1]` (instead of `[0]`) and keep copying until `length() - 1` bytes have been copied. (-1 because you want to omit the first character).

The final character then gets overwritten with the terminating `\0`, finalizing the string and disposing of the final character.

Of course this approach will cause problems if the string does not have at least 1 character, so you should check for that beforehand.

Comment: It won't put a \0 at the end. May as well just be a memcpy or std::copy.

Comment: Hmm...you're right. I forgot about that.